# Keras: Adaptive Max Pooling

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm working on the CNN, I have the images with different sizes and aspect ratio, resizing and center cropping the images in pre-processing step may loose some valuable information (specially from edges - right,left,up and down).
I think, the better way is to apply the adaptive max pooling (giving the targeted output dimensions) in order to resize the images before we pass it to our final layer. 
In keras, I can add a simple max pooling layer, but is there a way in keras to tell/bound the max pooling layer the output size? e.g: if an image is of 800x1520 but the required output is 200x200, the max pooling applies and the image resized to 200x200

Answer (score 5):

There is no "adaptive pooling layer" in Keras, but there is the family of [GlobalMaxPooling](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalmaxpooling1d) layers. They can deal with undefined input shapes (i.e. one dimension can be `None`), but always have the same output shape.

However, note that within a single batch, all inputs need to have exactly the same dimension. If all your images are of different size, that means that you are restricted to a batch size of 1, which will make training and inference painfully slow.

I suggest that you first try to see how well your model works when you resize all images to the same size, or if you pad the smaller images such that they reach the same dimensions as your largest image. Which of the two options works better obviously depends a lot on the images and your feature detection architecture, but due to the restriction mentioned above, working with variable input sizes should be the last option.

Comment: Can you justify why you say "working with variable input sizes should be the last option"?

Comment: Sure, sorry if that's not clear from my answer. The justification is this: "within a single batch, all inputs need to have exactly the same dimension. If all your images are of different size, that means that you are restricted to a batch size of 1, which will make training and inference painfully slow." Please don't hesitate to ask for further clarifications.